# $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}-\frac{k}{r^2} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r^ \, \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \right)-2f\right)+g(r,t)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-dynamics

Consider the following partial differential equation
$$
\frac{\partial f (r,t)}{\partial t} - \frac{k}{r^2} 
\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r^ \, \frac{\partial f (r,t)}{\partial r} \right) - 2f(r,t) \right)
+ \frac{f(r=1, t)}{r^2}  = 0\, , 
$$
subject to the boundary conditions
$$
\left. \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \right|_{r=1} = 0\, , \qquad f(r=\infty, t) = 0 \, , 
$$
together with the initial condition $f(r, t=0) = \epsilon$.
Here, $k$ and $\epsilon$ are positive real numbers, with $|\epsilon| \ll 1$

To search an analytical solution of this PDE, i used the method of separation of variables.
Accordingly, the solution is expressed as $f(r,t) = F(r)G(t)$.
Using this approach, it can be shown that $G(t)$ satisfies the following differential equation
$$
G'(t) + \operatorname{const.} G(t) = 0 \, .
$$
The latter admit the exponential function as a solution.
The problem is that, by considering an decaying exponential, one would obtain a vanishing solution in the long-time limit as $t \to \infty$.
This is in contradiction with the numerical solution where, for instance, $f(r=1,t)$ reached a steady/plateau value in the limit $t \to \infty$.
Does this mean that one cannot employ the method of separation of variables in this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that the equation in the title is the correct one and that in the text has some typo.

The general solution to $$\frac{\partial f (r,t)}{\partial t} - \frac{k}{r^2} 
\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r^ \, \frac{\partial f (r,t)}{\partial r} \right) - 2f(r,t) \right)
+ g(r)  = 0\, ,$$
is of the form $$f(r,t)=H(r,t)+P(r,t),$$
where $P(r,t)$ is any particular solution of the equation and $H(r,t)$ is the general solution of the homogeneous equation:$$\frac{\partial f (r,t)}{\partial t} - \frac{k}{r^2} 
\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r^ \, \frac{\partial f (r,t)}{\partial r} \right) - 2f(r,t) \right) = 0\ .$$

My guess is that you are forgoting the particular solution $P(r,t)$. A particular $P$ can be find assuming that it's a function of $r$ only. With this ansatz we get:
$$ - \frac{k}{r^2} 
\left( \frac{d}{dr} \left( r^ \, \frac{dP}{dr} \right) - 2P \right)
+ g(r)  = 0$$
wich simplifies to $$rP''+P'-2P=\frac{r^2g(r)}{k},$$
whoose solutions can be found with [modified Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1) and using the [variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters). Depending on your's $g(r)$ the form of the $P$ can be really ugly. But there's no contradiction. As you find, the $H(r,t)$ is a sum of terms $F(r)G(t)$ where the G's are decaying exponentials, so in the long-time limit your **full solution** $H+P$ tends to $P(r)$.

Comment: Thanks Diego for the answer. Sorry for the typo! Here, $g(r,t) = f(r=1, t)/r^2$. Corrected now

Comment: Are you sure of this? If so, I really don't know how to deal with the $F(1)$ therm in the equation for $F$. In any case, your domain is unbounded, so the general solution would be a integral over $l$ of terms like $C(l)G(lt)$, where $C(l)$ is a "density". Note that the final result can be way to unespected. Think in terms of the Laplace transform of some elementary functions.

Comment: Alright – i think that the solution will grow exponentially. i have managed to solve the problem numerically when additional modes are included (not mentioned in the question.) Thanks for the hints anyways.